# default_url_options and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

As ActionController::Base#default_url_options is deprecated, I wonder how to set default url options in rails3. The default url options are not static but dependent of the current request.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options

Thanks,
Corin

Comment: `ActionController::Base#default_url_options` [is *not* deprecated](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To set url options for current request use something like this in your controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def url_options
    { :profile => current_profile }.merge(super)
  end

end
```

Now, :profile => current_profile will be automerge to path/url parameters.

Example routing:

```
scope ":profile" do
  resources :comments
end
```

Just write:

```
comments_path
```

and if current_profile has set to_param to 'lucas':

```
/lucas/comments
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this the "official" rails 3.0/3.1 way?

Comment: Too bad, it throws an exception when it's declared as protected which is a must (otherwise it's exposed as an action). So it does not work.

Comment: It works for me in real project, I don't know why you think it exposes as an action, just remove default routing /:controller/(:action) from your routes. This method must be public.

Comment: It's also working for mailers, just define the method in your subclass of ActionMailer::Base :)

Comment: How would you set the options based on model attribute. For example, set `:profile` to `comment.user.city_name`, so we get `/newyork/comments/123`?

Comment: comments_path(:profile => comment.user.city_name, :id => comment.id)

Comment: @LukaszSliwa but how would you set the instance variable to for `current_profile`?

Answer (score 24):

I believe the preferred method is to now tell the router to handle this:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:foo]= 'bar'
```

You can put this line in either `routes.rb` or an initializer. Whichever you would prefer. You could even put it in your environment configs if the values change based on your environment.

Comment: But how can i make this dependent on the current request, so for example access instance variables?

Comment: Yeps, it's not thread safe. I did it through custom method and Thread.current

Comment: Looks like this is it for Rails 3.2.

Comment: Dumb question: where do you *put* this line? In routes.rb? In an initializer?

Comment: If you have to set this at the config level, how do you pass in a dynamic `account_id`? For example `scope '/:account_id'` - How would you be able to set `account_id` dynamically at the config level?

Comment: I just put this in the Application Controller and it worked for me. Not sure if that is the right place for it, but it works.

Comment: @DanTao You can put this line in either `routes.rb` or an initializer. Whichever you would prefer. You could even put it in your environment configs if the values change based on your environment.

Comment: This no longer works for Rails 5.1.4 for page rendering, but only works for rails console.

Answer (score 4):

That apidock.com link is misleading.  default_url_options is not deprecated.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default_url_options

Comment: I think the guides are out of date, not apidoc.  The method no longer works in Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3 specifically, the canonical way to do it is by adding a `default_url_options` method to your `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    {
        :host => "corin.example.com",
        :port => "80"  #  Optional. Set nil to force Rails to omit
                       #    the port if for some reason it's being
                       #    included when you don't want it.
    }
  end
end
```

I just had to figure this out myself, so I know it works.

This is adapted from the Rails 3 Guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/action_controller_overview.html#default_url_options

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'`

In the developemnt.rb / test.rb, can be more concise as following:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... other config ...

  routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
end
```