# Rails url options based on model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have routes defined like

```
scope ':cityname' do
  resources comments
end
```

Note `cityname = comment.user.cityname` so url helpers such as `comment_path(@comment)` can generate links like

```
/newyork/comments/1
/boston/comments/2
/miami/comments/3
```

How to set this `:cityname` url option based on the model attribute?

I found a related question here : [default_url_options and rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100954/default-url-options-and-rails-3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def url_options
    { :cityname => @comment.user.cityname }.merge(super)
  end

end

class YourController < ...

def calledaction
  @comment = Comment.find(1)
end
end
```

Comment: thanks but how'd it work on an index page with 100 comment links with all different citynames? i.e., is there a way to bypass ApplicationController at all?

Comment: It has to be overridden in controllers, so you can put this function inside your specific controllers, in case you dont want it everywhere.

Comment: still, how'd this work on the index page with 100 comment links, with all **DIFFERENT** citynames? Here you don't have a single @comment, but an array of comments, and how would a controller help here?

Comment: In that case you can try to pass on the cityname like this some_url(:cityname => 'cityname')