# Rails: configuring a form action's host using custom URL from settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, action

I have a Rails app that I am feeding cross domain in production. It needs absolute references. Because of this, I have enabled the following in my config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://myapp.herokuapp.com"
```

That works fine for images and resources but my input form that looks like this:

```
 <%= form_tag('/plans/collapse_plans', :method => 'post', :remote => true ) do %>
```

is still getting this in the console:

```
  Failed to load resource file://localhost/plans/collapse_plan
```

How can I change it so that form action will automatically include the specified host, instead of defaulting to localhost? Can I set this anywhere in config?

Comment: any reason you are using form_tag instead of form_for ?

Comment: @emaillenin no i was unaware of form_for, will that use the configured asset_host ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it will work:

https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic

Then I can just do:

```
<%= form_tag mysettings.myspecifiedhost + plans_collapse_plans_path, :method => 'post', :remote => true do %>
```

Comment: Using concatenation of strings to render URLs probably means there's a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

I may be on the wrong track here, but:

Asset host is not your application's host, asset host is a host that serves you `/app/assets` folder and this is configurable so you can set up a CDN for example, it's not intended for hosting action points.

If you want to target the full url of your own host use `rake routes` to get the route name corresponding to `/plans/collapse_plans` which probably looks something in the lines of `plans_collapse_plans` and then you can use `plans_collapse_plans_url` and rails will render the correct full URL for you.

**If you're using the default host name rails provides automagically this will "just work"**, i.e.

```
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x000000048fd780>>)> account_edit_url
=> "http://dev:3000/account/edit"
```

**If this doesn't "just work", you can override all url helpers** in the app by overriding `default_url_options` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def default_url_options
  {:host => HOST}
end
```

and be sure to set the `HOST` constant in your application's environment, for example:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x00000005047d10>>)> account_edit_url
=> "http://o7ms:3000/account/edit"
```

**If you need to override this just in certain situations** you can leave the `ApplicationController` alone and do:

```
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x000000048fd780>>)> account_edit_url(host: MY_HOST_FOR_THE_OTHER_THINGY)
=> "http://foo:3000/account/edit"
```

In all cases you'll set up a config option in one place and all endpoints in the app will adjust.

**EDIT**

**If you want to go fancy,**

see [default_url_options and rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100954/default-url-options-and-rails-3),

by overriding `url_options` you **may** be able to implement pretty calls like `account_edit_url(ajax_host: true)`, the `url_options` method would look something like this if this works:

```
def url_options
  options = super
  if super.delete(:ajax_host)
    {host: AJAX_HOST}.merge(options)
  else
    options
  end
end
```

Comment: This is REALLY good information.  You should have gotten this bounty.  Seeing how "rails magic" works is really important to me.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying cannot be done normally for ajax calls.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I only need to know how to set the action's host, I am aware of Same Origin Policy and have already gotten around this issue, what I am doing can be done with a rails plugin (i forget the name off the top of my head)

Comment: gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

this allows your rails app to respond to cross domain requests.

Comment: what you did is for assets. give the entire url in the form tag.

Comment: I know I can do it with the full URL, I'm trying to avoid that.  If I specify the path in active record, aka 'plans_collapse_plans_path' should that work? How can I give the method a host? I am looking for something I can add to the config so that it appluies universally.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:--

1.) `<%= form_tag root_url + plans_collapse_plans_path, :method => 'post', :remote => true do %>`

```
concatenation:-- root_url + plans_collapse_plans_path
```

2.) in config/environments/production.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # general configurations
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'root_url' #'localhost:3000'
  end
end
```